# Need a new category on close reasons

Tags: discussion, feature-request

There are some questions which need to be closed because information in the question is missing (e.g. pictures) and the user has not added the information despite reminders (comments) by other's.  We can only wait so long for the user to respond and if they don't we should close it.  I suggest adding a category for close reason for this scenario.  The current categories do not suffice.  What are your thoughts?  Are there other ways to close these old, incomplete questions?

Comment: What's wrong with **Unclear what you're asking**, which leaves guidance that reads: "Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question."

Comment: I guess that would work!  I was referring to questions that are dormant and the person asking the question is not responsive.  I guess I may be splitting hairs!

Comment: I see where you're going and think this is a good idea. For a quick fix in the meantime, @NiallC, can we change "See the How to Ask page" to "See the [What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on-hold?"](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions?)" page? Under the **Unclear what you're asking** close reason it says, "Edit your post to be more specific about what you're looking for, and be sure to address any concerns that other users brought up in the comments."  I try to point people there if I see this problem, but an official link would be better. What do you think?

Comment: @sue The close reason I quoted above is one of the canned reasons and it can't be changed. What we can do is create a custom close reason which explains better what's wrong with the question and what should be done to improve it. I was trying to be a bit facetious with my comment, but Alina is on the right track that a problem might be perfectly clear to the OP, but not clear to us because we can't see the plant, don't know the environment it was kept in, its watering schedule, feeding schedule, etc. etc.

Comment: @Niall C,  thanks for responding. I had a feeling we couldn't change that wording, but thought asking you was worth a shot! I'm glad we can make a new close reason if we want to after this discussion. I've always used "Unclear what you're asking" but like the idea of designing something more suitable. By the way,  I didn't see your comment to Alina as facetious!

Answer (score 7):

I am reluctant to use **Unclear what you're asking** because it's very clear what the OP asks: why is his tree dieing, how to prune a shrub, where to place a flower container, etc.

I feel that having a message like "Closed because it's unclear what you're asking" on a question that fails to provide enough info (although the question is comprehensible) only annoys the OP and brings insecurity to potential new askers.

Having a different message, something like "Closed because of insufficient data - it will be reopened when new info is added" might be more user-friendly in my opinion.

Comment: That is exactly my point and you said it much better than i did. Thank you